# Swift Keyboard Extension update NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm trying to make an iOS keyboard extension but I'm having trouble syncing/updating the data from the containing app to the extension.

As the doc states, I'm using

```
NSUserDefaults *mySharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"com.example.domain.MyShareExtension"];
[mySharedDefaults setObject:theAccountName forKey:@"lastAccountName"];
```

That works perfectly. Before launching the keyboard in the containing app, I use that, and in the keyboard's viewdidLoad I check NSUserDefault and everything works fine.

The problem is if in my containing app I update my NSUserDefaults, how can I know in my keyboard app that the NSUserDefaults have been updated.

I tried KVO, does not work.
I tried NSUserDefaultsStandard, with NSUserDidChangeNotification, does not work. NSUserDefaultsStandard does not work at all for the keyboard extension.

I was thinking of using an NSTimer in my keyboard extension, and check the NSUserDefaults every X ms. But it's overkill.

I know it's possible since apps are doing it in the AppStore. BrightKey or CoolKey change the keyboard design from the containing app.
So they definitely have a callback or something to update their data.

Thanks in advance for anyone coming up with a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can read/write values to the shared user defaults every time your keyboard and containing app load.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to do that without having to wait a load.
The app BrightKey and CoolKey change the design of the keyboard live for example, without reloading them.

Comment: They Show the keyboard while you choose a theme . They're doing the fleksy trick : when the keyboard is loaded, they input a very quick textual id into the text field that the keyboard recognizes and saves it locally

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? How does the keyboard access the textual id ? How does it now the id just changed so they can upload the theme in real time ?

Answer (score 0):

Mt trick is:

Just add a `UITextField` to your containing app, and set the `Hidden` property `On`, so the textfield is invisible.

After user selected any theme, just call `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` so it seems that you have loaded keyboard after user selected theme. after user selected another theme, just call `textView.resignFirstResponder()` and wait for about 0.6 seconds (so NSUserDefaults updates) and then again call `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` and your keyboard will load with new theme! :)

Comment: This is my current trick.
But if you check the 2 apps I mentioned they do not use that trick, since the keyboard never resigns.
It's a little ugly to have the keyboard disappear and come back after a short delay...